# Accessing Attributes of parent class

Tags: php, symfony, attributes, doctrine, php-8

I'm using PHP8 attributes to flag Doctrine entities in a Symfony project, to set the entity up for audit logging.
To determine whether the entity should be audited I would check whether it has an `#[Auditable]` attribute.

Everything works well until the entity is loaded using a Proxy, which is essentially a class extending the entity itself, but it fails my check whether the entity has the required attribute.

Here's the code I use to get class' attributes:

```
    public function getAttribute($entity, string $attributeClass): mixed
    {
        if (!is_object($entity)) {
            return null;
        }

        $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($entity);
        $reflectionAttr = $reflectionClass->getAttributes($attributeClass)[0] ?? null;

        return $reflectionAttr ? $reflectionAttr->newInstance() : null;
    }
```

Is there a way to check whether the original entity that has been proxied has an attribute?

I did try eager loading the entities but it wasn't reliable as it still shows up ad a Proxy class in some situations, so rather than trying to enforce the "real" entity I believe there's a better way to work with Doctrine, not against it.

Another option would be an interface, but I'm trying to keep the code minimal and it feels like an attribute is better suited for this job if I can make it work with Doctrine's proxy.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14895345

```
$list = (new \ReflectionClass(ClassUtils::getClass($object)))->getAttributes($class);
```

ClassUtils::getClass extracts original class name whether its proxy or not.